# VB programming. Integer array and prime numbers

Tags: vb.net, primes

I'm new to programming and stack overflow blogs, so hopefully I am following the 'do's and dont's' properly.

I have been given an assignment question asking me to store 5 integers in an array and to determine if they are a prime number or not.

The questions I have are as follows:

1. How do I store them into an integer array?
2. How do I make my program divide every input by every number less than the input?

The code I have written so far is this:

Sub Main()

```
    Dim a, b, c, d, e As Integer
    Dim isPrime As Boolean = True

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for a: ")
    a = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for b: ")
    b = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for c: ")
    c = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for d: ")
    d = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for e: ")
    e = Console.ReadLine



    If a Mod (a - 1) > 0 Or a = 2 And a <> 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("a is a prime number")
    ElseIf a Mod (a - 1) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("a is not a prime number")
    End If

    If b Mod (b - 1) > 0 Or b = 2 And b <> 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("b is a prime number")
    ElseIf b Mod (b - 1) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("b is not a prime number")
    End If

    If c Mod (c - 1) > 0 Or c = 2 And c <> 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("c is a prime number")
    ElseIf c Mod (c - 1) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("c is not a prime number")
    End If

    If d Mod (d - 1) > 0 Or d = 2 And d <> 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("d is a prime number")
    ElseIf d Mod (d - 1) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("d is not a prime number")
    End If

    If e Mod (e - 1) > 0 Or e = 2 And e <> 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("e is a prime number")
    ElseIf e Mod (e - 1) = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("e is not a prime number")
    End If

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

Learning all of this stuff with the prior knowledge provided has made things difficult, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim a, b, c, d, e As Integer

Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for a: ")
a = Console.ReadLine
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for b: ")
b = Console.ReadLine
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for c: ")
c = Console.ReadLine
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for d: ")
d = Console.ReadLine
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for e: ")
e = Console.ReadLine

Dim intary() As Integer = {CInt(a), CInt(b), CInt(c), CInt(d), CInt(e)}
For Each number As Integer In intary
    Dim prime As Boolean = True
    For x As Integer = 2 To number - 1
        If number Mod x = 0 Then
            prime = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If prime Then
        Console.WriteLine(number.ToString & " IS a prime number")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(number.ToString & " IS NOT a prime number")
    End If
Next
```

The integer array is created in the first line. Then, the concept is you would want to iterate through each item in the array, and run a prime number test on it. So, we have a for loop that will run our prime number test on each number in the array. For each of the numbers, we divide the test-number by every number from two all the way up to the given test-number and check the mod remainder. If any of those return zero besides the number itself, then we do not have a prime number. In the example shown, I am just printing a simple line stating whether or not each number passed or failed the test...hope this helps and good luck learning your new language!

Side note, you could dim the array and add each new number as it's retrieved from the user, but you would need to redim or resize the array each time. The example I wrote just uses the input logic you already had in place. If the assignment didn't explicitly ask for an array, you'd be able to write a much cleaner solution if you were to use a list.

Comment: You sir, are a saint. I totally get it now!

Comment: I am going to get back to work so someday I might be able to pay it forward!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If you do not have any secondary questions on this topic, it's good practice to mark it as answered. That both marks the post as containing an accepted solution for other StackOverflow users, and also shoots a couple of points my way ;)

Comment: The only issue that I have had is that the program (that I tailored a little) seems to want to exit straight after making calculations.

Comment: Figured it out... Obvious really... Thanks!

Comment: You can check the 2-case first and make the loop stop at `sqrt(number)` with a step of 2

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer to this question is to take the users inputs, and to run a mod on each of these numbers between 2 and the users input.

To the people who are starting out like me, my advice is that you don't differ from the basic idea and it will all eventually make sense!