# Simplest way to print and get the sum of Prime number within a range in vb.net WITHOUT using arrays, recursions or anything related to it

Tags: vb.net, oop, primes

The given problem is to print and get the sum of all prime numbers within a range in the simplest way

Example is:

Minimum Number: 1

Max Number: 15

Prime Numbers: 2 3 5 7 11 13

Sum: 41

The catch is I am not allowed to use recursions, arrays or anything related to it. As far as I know, I only allowed using Do Loop, For, Do until etc.

I'm still transitioning from Java into this language. And Sorry for my English.

Comment: Modify [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39113340/6664878)...just have to change the for-loop to iterate integers within a range, and "if prime" to add the number to a sum variable. If you get stuck post your problem

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Write a boolean function `isPrime(n)` to tell if number `n` is prime.

Step 2: incorporate your function into a loop, checking all numbers in the given range and increasing your running total as needed.

Hint: you can save time by dealing with even numbers separately: 2 is prime, all other even numbers aren't prime, so there is no need to check them.